# Javascript function that not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function which is use to check *Chinese* input in a `textarea` then set the maximum length , it works with *IE*, *Opera*, *Chrome* except *Firefox*.
Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Just in case....I will put my function here....

```
function testChinese() {
    countA = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<bulksend.inputtext.value.length; i++) {
        curText = bulksend.inputtext.value.charCodeAt(i);
        if(curText > 127) { 
            countA += 1;
        }
    }
    if(countA>0)
        return true;
}
function setlength() {
    min = 0;
    limit = 0;
    if(testChinese() == true) {
        min = 70;
        limit = 66;
    } else {
        min = 160;
        limit = 156;
    }
    var typedtext = document.getElementById('inputtext').value;

    // continue.......

}
```

Thanks for every reply .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "bulksend" is the "id" of your `<form>`, you can try this:

```
     function testChinese() {
       var bulksend = document.getElementById('bulksend');
```

That should work in all browsers.

Comment: Thank you so much Pointy!! It works now! 
Really thanks for your help...

Need to wait for another 8 minutes to accept this answer.

Comment: Glad to have been able to help!